# Named argument specifications must appear after all fixed arguments have been specified while having two routes.MapRoute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

what needs to be change in routing? as it is working in local machine but in CI build getting failed I can't understand how to fix this problem

```
 routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Landing",
           url: "{action}/",
           new { controller = "Landing", action = "Home" }
       );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first call to `MapRoute()` has two named arguments followed by an unnamed one.

This is only supported by the C# language 7.2 or later. It seems like your CI build machine must have an earlier version of Visual Studio than your local machine does.

You should be able to replicate this compile error on your local machine by adding the following to the `<PropertyGroup>` that contains the `<TargetFramework>` specification in your project's `.csproj` file:

```
<LangVersion>7.1</LangVersion>
```

If you change that to:

```
<LangVersion>7.2</LangVersion>
```

or later, the error will go away.

Your solution ideally is to update Visual Studio to the latest version on your CI build machine. If you can't do that, you should set `<LangVersion>` for your projects to match the highest supported version on your build PCs, so that you are alerted to these issues before you check the code in.